# Is it possible to build a Perl wrapper around the GNOME terminal?

Tags: perl, gnome

Is it possible to build a Perl wrapper around the GNOME terminal which would help me to pass commands to it and also capture the ouputs on the terminal?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I have the strong feeling that the gnome-terminal application does not need to be involved at all.

Comment: If you want to script interaction with command line apps look at http://search.cpan.org/dist/Expect/Expect.pod (Expect) or http://search.cpan.org/dist/IPC-Run/lib/IPC/Run.pm  (IPC::Run) instead, or even http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-VT102/VT102.pm (Term::VT102) which lets you manage a virtual  VT102 'screen' in memory.

Comment: I am running a perl script that is communicating with the router . If the script fails , when a wrong router command is given , then the error generated should show up on the gui

Comment: You can use print and warn to print to the terminal (STDOUT), a file or a named pipe

Comment: IPC::Run has start(), pump() and finish() which lets you combine your router command loop with your GUI / Event loop.

Comment: Expect has similar commands (as does Net::Telnet, which also returns the connection to the server as a filehandle you can use in a select() loop, or add a watcher on in your GUI's event loop)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use [Gnome2::Vte](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Gnome2-Vte) (I don't know how maintained / bug-free it is, YMMV) to create your own gnome-terminal alike (gnome terminal uses libvte) instead of wrapping the terminal.